# Trying to get the information of session WebFlow Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm trying to get the information of the session created with spring security. I want to get it in a flow of spring webflow. I tryed this:

```
<evaluate expression="SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()" result="flowScope.information"/>
```

But it doesn't works...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the special EL variable `currentUser` to get access to the Authentication object:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#el-variable-currentUser